# React router with basename and webpack initial url

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server

Hello i am stuck with this one and couldnt figure it out. So i have React router v6 with `basename - "/ui/"` , and i want that when i open `localhost:8080`  that it automatically turns into `"localhost:8080/ui/"` because the real view is actually rendered in `/ui/` route.

Router setup:

```
<BrowserRouter basename="/ui/">
       ...routes here
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Webpack dev:

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        open: true,
        port: 6969
    }
}
```

And common webpack:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './src/index.tsx'),
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.(ts|js)x?$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader',
                    },
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                use: [
                    // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
                    "style-loader",
                    // Translates CSS into CommonJS
                    "css-loader",
                    // Compiles Sass to CSS
                    "sass-loader"
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.(?:ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$/i,
                type: 'asset/resource',
            },
            {
                test: /\.(woff(2)?|eot|ttf|otf|svg|)$/,
                type: 'asset/inline',
            },
        ],
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './build'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, '..', './src/public/ui/index.html'),
        }),
    ],
    stats: 'errors-only',
```

}

I have tried to add to output `publicPath: '/ui/'` but it didnt work.
Or even something like this:

```
static: [
            {
                publicPath: '/',
                directory: path.join(__dirname, "../public/ui/"),
            }]
```

How i can achieve this withouth "redirecting" :\

Comment: Did you solve it? I'm going to try solving this and I hope you can solve it too (if you haven't)!

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a year old thread, but it may help someone else.

I faced similar issue and it happens, because from `react-router-dom` version 6 the `basename` is not redirecting automatically to the basename path anymore.

My solution was to run this code:

```js
if (!window.location.pathname.includes(process.env.PUBLIC_URL)) {
    const currentPathname = window.location.pathname
    window.location.pathname = process.env.PUBLIC_URL + currentPathname
}

export default function App(){
  return(
    <BrowserRouter basename={process.env.PUBLIC_URL}>
      {// ...more code}
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this solution](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/how-to-set-react-router-default-route-redirect-to-home)

```
<Route exact path="/">
  <Redirect to="/home" />
</Route>
```

Comment: This does't work for me. I think the react ruoter doesn't get triggered unless there is the "/ui" in the url :\

Answer (score 0):

Check your `main.js` or similar in your `src` or `sources`.
Mine had:

```
const Root = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        {appRoute}
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);
```

and so just had to move it to `Route path="/ui/" component={App}`